# Match ip against list with CIDR notations and comment

Tags: bash, ip

I'm trying to match an ip address (ie 192.168.192.168) against a list:

192.168.192.0/24 TESTCOMMENT
...

I know `ipset` supports comments so I tried the following:

```
$ ipset create foo hash:net comment
$ ipset add foo 192.168.192.0/24 comment TESTCOMMENT
$ sudo ipset test foo 192.168.192.168
192.168.192.168 is in set foo.
```

As you can see I the comment is not shown. My next try was making use of `grepcidr`

```
$ cat foo.txt 
192.168.192.0/24 TESTCOMMENT
$ grepcidr -f foo.txt <(echo 192.168.192.168)
192.168.192.168
$ grepcidr -f foo.txt <(echo 192.168.0.168)
$
```

This matches but does not show the comment.

Does someone know an alternative to try out?

Comment: Like grep, grepcidr uses `-f` to load *patterns* from a file, not the text to match. So your command is probably like regular grep one `grepcidr '192.168.0.168' foo.txt`, `grep pattern file`.

Comment: @LuisMuñoz You're right the syntax was wrong, but could come up with the correct one. Sadly grepcidr needs an cidr notation for pattern to match IP addresses. Vice versa it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of someone else we've tackled the problem. We used rgxg to change the subnet in the file to a regex.

```
$awk -v ip=192.168.192.168 '{ "rgxg cidr " $1 | getline regex; if (ip ~ regex) print $2 }' foo.txt
TESTCOMMENT
```

The solution I use is to save the regex to the file:

192.168.192.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9]?[0-9]) TESTCOMMENT

and use the following line to test the IP address:

```
$ ip=192.168.192.168; while read line; do [[ $ip =~ ${line%% *} ]] && echo ${line##* }; done < foo.txt
TESTCOMMENT
```